# Не идет выполнение AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION

Tags: sql, oracle

привет .

```
CREATE TABLE wio(id number(5) CONSTRAINT pks CHECK( id IN (3,5,6,7,10)),status number(5) )
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE Automomous AS
PRAGMA AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION; 
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO wio VALUES(10,10);
  commit;
END Automomous;

TRUNCATE TABLE wio;
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE child_block IS
BEGIN
  savepoint foo;
  INSERT INTO wio VALUES(4,200);
  Automomous;
  exception
   when others then rollback to foo; 
                    RAISE;
END;
/
EXEC child_block();
```

Когда вызываю функцию я получаю ошибку

> 2290. 00000 -  "check constraint (%s.%s) violated"
>         *Cause:    The values being inserted do not satisfy the named check
>
> *Action:   do not insert values that violate the constraint

Но я ведь использую exception roolback . Почему не идет подавление появление этой ошибки? 
`AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` не вызывается и таблица пустая . Как вызвать `AUTONOMOUS_TRANSACTION` даже если функция выполняется с ошибкой ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Ошибка подавляется, но потом Вы заново ее выбрасываете вызовом [RISE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14261/raise_statement.htm) в блоке exception.
2. Когда при вставке данных возникает ошибка, то выполнение процедуры сразу переходит к блоку exception. Поэтому, если Вам нужно, чтобы процедура Autonomous обязательно вызывалась - Вы можете вызывает ее до вставки данных.

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE child_block IS
    BEGIN
      savepoint foo;
      Automomous;
      INSERT INTO wio VALUES(4,200);
      exception
       when others then rollback to foo; 
    END;
```

Comment: спасибо за внимание к вопросу.